# Wide character in print when involve using special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I want to split a long sentence with the dot `.`  character as long as the dot is not wrapped in any kinds of brackets, like (), （）, 【】, 〔〕, etc. and there should be at least three words on its left. I use the following code. But it gives the `Wide character in print` error.

```
my $a = "hi hello world. "
$a .= "【 hi hello world.  】";    
my @list = split /(?<!\.)(?<=(?:[\w'’]{1,30} ){2}[\w'’]{1,30})\. (?![^()〈〉【】（）\[\]〔〕\{\}]*[\)）\]〉】〕\}])/, $a;
```

The expected result would be $a splits into:
`hi hello world`
and
`【 hi hello world.  】`

I'm using perl v5.31.3 on macOS Big Sur.

p.s. In the project, I'm also using `XML::LibXML::Reader`. I'm not sure whether adding `use utf8::all;` is allowed.

Comment: If your source is saved as utf-8, `use utf8;`.  If your input is encoded in utf-8, set the binmode or decode it.

Comment: I have added `use utf8;`, but not seems to work.

Comment: Do you mean the regex /…/ should be decoded?

Comment: Is the regex comming from an external file?

Comment: The regex is passed through from the command line option. But it's the same error if the regex is written within the perl file.

Comment: Very strange… After I add `no warnings qw(experimental::vlb);` all works fine. Although if regex is passed through command line, I need to decode it.

Comment: Running perl with `-CA` decodes the arguments for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode your inputs, encode your outputs

---

The warning is the result of your attempt to write something other than bytes<sup>[1]</sup> to a file handle.

You need to encode your outputs, either explicitly, or by adding an encoding layer to the file handle.

```perl
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

---

If your source code is encoded using UTF-8, you need to tell `perl` that by using `use utf8;`. Otherwise, it assumes the source code is encoded using ASCII.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

If you accept arguments, these are also inputs that need to be decoded. You can use the following:

```perl
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

@ARGV = map { decode_utf8($_) } @ARGV;
```

---

1. For this purpose, a byte is a value between 0 and 255 inclusive. And since we're talking about printing, we're talking about a character (which is to say string element) with such a value.
2. Although string and regex literals are 8-bit clean.

Comment: Added to my answer.